# Why is this sentence written “Je n'ai pas de voiture”?

Tags: conjugaison

When I wanted to write “I don't have a car” in French, I wrote it as follows:

> *J'ai n'a pas de voiture*

But, how it was written in the book I'm reading was as follows:

> *Je n'ai pas de voiture*

Why the `i` here? Isn't my sentence correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of those sentence is correct. A correct sentence would be

> *Je n'ai pas de voiture*

Which breaks down into

- *Je* → I
- *n'* → a contraction of *ne*, first part of the negative cluster *ne pas*
- *ai* → *avoir* first person singular, *présent simple de l'indicatif* which translates to present *have*
- *pas* → second part of the negative cluster *ne pas*
- *de voiture* → *a car*. I won't go into subtleties such as why it is *de* and not *une*, as it is off-topic here

The first issue with your sentence *Je* is replaced by *J'ai* which is a (mandatory) contraction for **Je ai*. It could be a mishearing, but it is fundamentally wrong, as it introduce an extraneous verb in the sentence, as if you wrote in English “I have do not have a car”.

In addition to this, the *a* is a conjugation mistake. The first person singular *présent simple de l'indicatif* of *avoir* is *ai*, not *a*. As is, it is as if you wrote <del>[“I don't has a car”](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-CzqzzBV2tMk/TxBM3ar18MI/AAAAAAAAPm0/6faLPO9BM8w/s1600/i-can-has-cheezburger.jpg)</del>. For future reference, as *avoir* is one of the most irregular verbs in French, if in doubt, check [a conjugation table](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/avoir.php).